# how to remove duplicates from two array of object by using ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

i am trying to remove duplicates from userPermitDataArr.

```
deniedModuleArr = [ { moduleName: 'Transaction fee',
    url: '/transactionfee',
    moduleClassName: 'TransactionFee' },
  { moduleName: 'Refund View',
    url: '/refundview',
    moduleClassName: 'RefundView' } ]

userPermitDataArr = [ { moduleName: 'Transaction fee',
    url: '/transactionfee',
    moduleClassName: 'TransactionFee' },
  { moduleName: 'Refund View',
    url: '/refundview',
    moduleClassName: 'RefundView' },
  { moduleName: 'Cancellation',
    url: '/cancellation',
    moduleClassName: 'Cancellation' },
  { moduleName: 'Transaction',
    url: '/transaction',
    moduleClassName: 'Transaction' } ]


 [{ moduleName: 'Cancellation',
    url: '/cancellation',
    moduleClassName: 'Cancellation' },
  { moduleName: 'Transaction',
    url: '/transaction',
    moduleClassName: 'Transaction' } ]
```

Comment: You going to merge two array by removing duplicated ?

Comment: Please, edit your answer - add description what exactly is wrong / error is occuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the naming convention & the expected result it seems you need to filter out denied modules from user permit modules. You can try following.

Firstly create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of `userPermitDataArr` and then [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) `userPermitDataArr` based on the above created set.

```js
let deniedModuleArr = [{ moduleName: 'Transaction fee',url: '/transactionfee',moduleClassName: 'TransactionFee' },{ moduleName: 'Refund View',url: '/refundview',moduleClassName: 'RefundView' } ];
let userPermitDataArr = [ { moduleName: 'Transaction fee',url: '/transactionfee', moduleClassName: 'TransactionFee' },{ moduleName: 'Refund View',url: '/refundview',moduleClassName: 'RefundView' },{ moduleName: 'Cancellation',url: '/cancellation',moduleClassName: 'Cancellation' },{ moduleName: 'Transaction',url: '/transaction',moduleClassName: 'Transaction' } ];
    
let deniedModuleSet = deniedModuleArr.reduce((a,c) => a.add(c.moduleName), new Set());
userPermitDataArr = userPermitDataArr.filter(v => !deniedModuleSet.has(v.moduleName));
console.log(userPermitDataArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HashSet` this approach can be used to check object equality for nested structures as well.

```js
const aStr = firstArr.map(o => JSON.stringify(o));
const bStr = secondArr.map(o => JSON.stringify(o));

const set = new Set();
set.add(...aStr);
set.add(...bStr);

console.log([...set.values()].map(o => JSON.parse(o)));
```